# Read one csv file and write to another csv file after doing some formatting in perl

Tags: csv, perl

I am trying to manipulate a csv in perl.

The input csv has some new line characters in column data which is causing an other external program to fail. I have wrote below Perl script to do pre-process the csv to remove these characters.

```
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';

# Using Text::CSV file to allow 
# full CSV Reader and Writer 
use Text::CSV; 
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die; 

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( 
{ 
    binary => 1, 
    auto_diag => 1, 
    sep_char => ', '
}); 

my $sum = 0; 

# Reading the file 
open(my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $file) or die; 

while (my $words = $csv->getline($data))  
{ 
    tr/\r\n//d for @$words; #removing new lines
    tr/,/;/ for @$words;    #replacing comma with semicolon
    $csv->combine(@$words);
    print $csv->string, "\n";
} 

# Checking for End-of-file 
if (not $csv->eof)  
{ 
    $csv->error_diag(); 
} 
close $data;
```

I am using a below shell script as a wrapper to store the modified file in another csv. Shell wrapper below.

```
perl xyz.pl ${source_csv_file_name} > ${destination_processed_csv_file_name}
```

I was hoping I could use a out csv handler in the perl script itself to write the ouput to another file. I tried couple of ways but keep getting one or other error. Below is something which I tried.

```
my $outcsv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, quote_char => "", escape_char => "\\" } );
open(my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $file) or die; 
open(my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "new.csv") or die " new.csv: $!";
while (my $words = $csv->getline($data))  
{ 
    tr/\r\n//d for @$words;
    tr/,/;/ for @$words;
    $csv->combine(@$words);
    # Open a handle to the file "new.csv"
    $outcsv->print ($fh, $_) for @words;

    #print $csv->string, "\n";
} 

# Checking for End-of-file 
if (not $csv->eof)  
{ 
    $csv->error_diag(); 
} 
close $data;
close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
```

Issue is the first code that I posted above works but to write the file I have used the shell wrapper. Now the second perl script (I have only posted the code which is different then the first one ), when I run it fails with an error. I understand the error but not sure how to fix it "Global symbol @words requires explicit package name at xyz.pl line 29. Execution of xyz.pl aborted due to compilation errors. 
Would really appreciate if someone can help here.

Thanks

Comment: Would really appreciate if you post example data here.

Comment: Also, tell us what (and how) fails

Comment: ok, The first code that I posted works but to write the file I have used the shell wrapper. Now the second perl script (I have only posted the code which is different then the first one )when I run it fails with below error. I understand the error but not sure how to fix it "Global symbol  ```@words requires explicit package name at d2l_preprocess_csv_files.pl line 29.
Execution of d2l_preprocess_csv_files.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
"```

Comment: Alright, thanks for responding.  This kind of info needs to be in the question to start with.  (Example: I spotted right away that you have a `@words` in your second program -- a typo in posting, I thought, whereby you accidentally dropped that `$`.  But once you showed the error we know that _that_ actually was a problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what failed for you in the first program, but here it is a bit streamlined and cleaned up

```
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';

use Text::CSV; 
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 }); 

open my $data,   '<',        $file or die $!; 
open my $fh_out, '>', 'new_'.$file or die $!; 

while (my $words = $csv->getline($data))  
{ 
    tr/\r\n//d for @$words;
    tr/,/;/    for @$words;

    $csv->say($fh_out, $words);
}
```

This runs correctly, and is nicely tested with an input file borrowed from [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60965755/4653379).

The `combine`+`string`+`print` from your program works as well for me -- but there is no reason for all that since `print` nicely combines them (I used `say` which also appends a newline).

A few comments on the program in the question

- Once you've used the `open` pragma as in your program then don't set encoding when you open files. (And it should be `:encoding(UTF-8)`, not with `utf8`. See about that [in Encode docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8), and in this [*Effective Perler* article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/08/know-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf-8/).)
- When you use `die` print the actual error, most commonly in [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)
- The two loops above are clearly less efficient than

  ```
  for (@$words) { tr/\r\n//d; tr/,/;/ }
  ```

  I left them as two loops to indicate separate processing steps.

---

The method `say` in `Text::CSV` used above was added to the module at some point, and a version older than that one won't have it.  Then one can

- Use `print` method and also set up `eol` in the constructor to get newlines printed

  ```
  my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ });
  ...
  $csv->print($fh_out, $words);
  ```

  (there are other ways to get the newline, see docs [for `eol`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#eol))
- Or, don't mess with the constructor but add that newline manually

  ```
  $csv->print($fh_out, $words);
  print $fh_out "\n";
  ```
- Or, use the roundabout way

  ```
  $csv->combine(@$words);
  print $fh_out $csv->string, "\n";
  ```

See docs [for print](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#print)

Comment: Thanks @zdim ! My first program works fine but like I said It doesn't write to a file instead it writes to stdout. My second program fails . I have given the error message in the comment above. I will test your approach and let you know how I go.

Comment: Hi @zdim. When I run the above program it gives me an error.  "Can't locate method say at xyz.pl line 18."  My perl version is "This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi"

Comment: @giri Ah, that means that your `Text::CSV` is older than whenever they introduced `say` method (it was added at one point).  Then use their `print` instead

Comment: @giri  (But I have the same Perl, and my `Text::CSV` (version 1.33) has `say`...?)

Comment: @giri  Added options to the end of the answer

Comment: @giri Please note that a comment had a typo, which would make it fail in a weird way. I've removed that comment since I've added details to the answer (without typos I hope!)

Comment: May be because of my Text::CSV version . I printed these out Text::CSV->VERSION1.30
Text::CSV->version1.00

Comment: @giri  Right, must be that ... which is a puzzle as I have the same Perl version (so I'd imagine the same module version as well?).  You can find the version by looking a t the beginning of the module's file, which you can locate by typing in the shell `perldoc -l Text::CSV` (that's ell, for Location).  But all workarounds that I added should work. Or update the module

Comment: Thanks for all help @zdim. And since I am fairly new to Stack overflow . My up-votes will not appear as score until I have a minimum reputation of 15. "_Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._"

Comment: @giri Glad to help :).  As for upvotes, thank you for considering -- it's OK, you can just "accept" for now (whichever answer you choose).  You can always come back and also vote on any and all answers you want (and questions)

Comment: @giri Thank you for attribution.  Please let me know if further questions on this pop up

Comment: All good now @zdim  . Just completed my script . Big help. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

The [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module (Installed through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client) makes it easy to transform CSV files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::AutoCSV;

Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file => $ARGV[0],
                   out_file => $ARGV[1],
                   encoding => "UTF-8",
                   has_headers => 1, # Set to 0 if no header line
                   read_post_update_hr => \&normalize)->write();

sub normalize {
    my $hr = shift;
    for (values %$hr) {
        s/\r?\n//g;
        tr/,/;/;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$ cat input.csv
id,message
1,"a string, with a comma"
2,"another
with a newline"
3,blah
$ perl demo.pl input.csv new.csv
$ cat new.csv
id,message
1,"a string; with a comma"
2,"another with a newline"
3,blah
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. ! I will see if I have this module installed already in the server . I am afraid I won't be able to try this if its not installed already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
while (my $words = $csv->getline($data))  
{ 
    tr/\r\n//d for @$words;
    tr/,/;/ for @$words;
    $csv->combine(@$words);
    # Open a handle to the file "new.csv"
    $outcsv->print ($fh, $_) for @words;

    #print $csv->string, "\n";
}
```

And, in a comment, you give us the error:

> Global symbol @words requires explicit package name at d2l_preprocess_csv_files.pl line 29.

I'm guessing that line 29 is:

```
$outcsv->print ($fh, $_) for @words;
```

The call to `getline()` gives you an array reference that you store in `$words`. If you want to treat that as an array, you need to dereference it (`@$words` - as you do in a few places). So on the problematic line you've just forgotten the `$`. You don't have an array called `@words`, you need to use `$@words`.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your response. Tried your suggestion but still getting an error "Expected fields to be an array ref at xyz.pl line 29, <$data> line 1."

Comment: @giri: Well, my fix would stop the initial error that you reported. It's hard to give much more help without seeing what your current code looks like.